# CSS touch-action: not always disabling in Cordova app

Tags: android, css, cordova

## Question

What am I missing in my CSS to make the results more consistent for no touch actions in my Cordova app?

---

I am building an app with Cordova (testing on Android). We had a full page selection come up that's not supposed to scroll so I used `touch-action: none` in the CSS. But it still scrolls but only sometimes.

### CSS

```
body {
    touch-action: none;
}
```

Now I'm showing different "pages" by turning on/off different divs in the html.  And what has me super confused is that when it goes to the first page it will scroll.... once!  And only once.  So I can tap the screen and drag the page up/down, let go and I can't scroll again.

BUT.
I go to the second page and it will do the same thing.  It will let me scroll once, but any further touch events get ignored.

The issue with this is my fancy html selector is suffering from this.  Where it will work, but periodically allow the page to scroll when it shouldn't.

My understanding is that "touch-action: none" should kill all touch events on Android not just some of them.

Answer (score 0):

After more digging I was able to solve this.

Quick answer.  `touch-action: none;` is perfectly fine.

What wasn't fine was that I was using Chrome's remote developer tools to connect to the device and watch the console. To see what was going on with the app at run time.  Because you can touch the application through the developer tools I'm guessing it was managing to screw up touch events. As in ignoring `touch-action:none` and forcing touch actions to happen.  Even if you touched only the real device and not the device "sim" through the developer tools it was still screwing up touch events.

So the solution.  You can use the developer tools to make sure you've added the css correctly.  Then close the developer tools for the device and run it again in cordova using `cordova run android` and don't connect using the developer tools.

I spent two working days trying to solve this.   :(